# Разделить ресурсы сервера между пользователями хостинга

Tags: linux, хостинг

Как разделить ресурсы выделенного сервера/*VDS* между пользователями и ограничить ими (для хостинга)?

*CloudLinux* не подходит.

Можно ли разделить ресурсы без установки специальных ОС (*CloudLinux*)?

Comment: *CloudLinux не подходит*. не могли бы вы раскрыть мысль — почему именно не подходит? к слову: это не операционная система, а [набор пакетов](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/converting_existing_servers.html), устанавливаемых в дистрибутив *centos* операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нужно поставить на Debian.Панель самописанная.Нету ли других способов разделить ресурсы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

разделением ресурсов занимается ядро операционной системы — в современных версиях программы (библиотеки) `linux` есть вся необходимая функциональность.

вопрос разве что в удобстве управления этим «хозяйством».

набор патчей и программ, разработанных для упомянутого дистрибутива *cloudlinux* операционной системы *gnu/linux*, основанного на другом дистрибутиве той же операционной системы — *centos*, представляет собой интегрированное «решение» для такого управления. кстати, установленный дистрибутив *centos* «[лёгким движением руки](http://docs.cloudlinux.com/converting_existing_servers.html)», т.е. с помощью установки нужных пакетов, «превращается» в дистрибутив *cloudlinux*.

кстати, исходники своих пакетов (не знаю, всех или только части) команда *cloudlinux* выкладывает в [свободный доступ на своём сайте](https://docs.docker.com/). вот, к примеру, [*src.rpm*-ы для версии 7](http://repo.cloudlinux.com/cloudlinux/7/updates/Sources/SPackages/). насколько можно догадаться, изменённые (по сравнению с *centos*-овскими) пакеты содержат в названии файла слово *cloudlinux*. при необходимости можно попробовать портировать эти исходники в используемый вами дистрибутив. или, на худой конец, хотя бы ознакомиться с ними.

насколько я понимаю, пакетами из *cloudlinux* используются те же механизмы [*lxc*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXC), что и, к примеру, популярной ныне программой [`docker`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker), которую в *jessie* можно установить из репозитория [`backports`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/docker.io). с управлением ресурсами при помощи *docker-а* можно начать знакомиться по какой-нибудь [обзорной статье](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/), а дальше по [документации на сайте](https://docs.docker.com/).